# Error max value gauge-solid

Tags: highcharts

I'm using my gauge-solid max value of 5 but on the chart the max value is 6
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You should definitely add a link to JSFIDDLE, from this screenshot. So someone can help u

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. You can adjust this fiddle to show the problem http://jsfiddle.net/0smcafvx/